# Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.7.1 [1] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc.. "

Tags: php, yii2, email, mail.ru

Столкнулась с такой проблемой, при регистрации на сайте через емайл example@mail.ru выходит ошибка:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.7.1 [1] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1528369324-lEDImbllLU-24v0Vfnp"
```

Но когда регистрируюсь через почтовый сервер example@yandex.ru, такая проблема не выскакивает. То есть ошибка выскакивает при регистрации через почтовый сервер @mail.ru Что это может быть?

Вот на всякий случай файл RegForm.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: coinfactory.pw
 * Date: 02.05.2015
 * Time: 18:17
 */

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

class RegForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $email;
public $password;
public $status;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'email', 'password'],'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['username', 'email', 'password'],'required'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'max' => 255],
        ['username', 'unique',
            'targetClass' => User::className(),
            'message' => 'Это имя уже занято.'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique',
            'targetClass' => User::className(),
            'message' => 'Эта почта уже занята.'],
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE, 'on' => 'default'],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' =>[
            User::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE,
            User::STATUS_ACTIVE
        ]],
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => User::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE, 'on' => 'emailActivation'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'Имя пользователя',
        'email' => 'Эл. почта',
        'password' => 'Пароль'
    ];
}

public function reg()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->status = $this->status;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();
    if($this->scenario === 'emailActivation')
        $user->generateSecretKey();
    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}

public function sendActivationEmail($user)
{
    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('activationEmail', ['user' => $user])
        ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name.' (отправлено роботом).'])
        ->setTo($this->email)
        ->setSubject('Активация для '.Yii::$app->name)
        ->send();
}
}
```

SendEmailForm.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: User
 * Date: 05.08.2015
 * Time: 15:21
*/
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class SendEmailForm extends Model
{
public $email;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => User::className(),
            'filter' => [
                'status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ],
            'message' => 'Данный емайл не зарегистрирован.'
        ],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'Емайл'
    ];
}
public function sendEmail()
{
    /* @var $user User */
    $user = User::findOne(
        [
            'status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE,
            'email' => $this->email
        ]
    );
    if($user):
        $user->generateSecretKey();
        if($user->save()):
            return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('resetPassword', ['user' => $user])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name.' (отправлено роботом)'])
                ->setTo($this->email)
                ->setSubject('Сброс пароля для '.Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        endif;
    endif;
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: вы прежде чем сюда писать, напишите в гугл "Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM"

Comment: @madfan41k Я гуглила но никаких решений кроме как "обратитесь в службу поддержки сервера отклонившего моё письмо, чтобы выяснить причины проблемы." я не нашла, поэтому сначало написала сюда.. может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Не понимаю почему моё письмо было распознано как спам.. Ведь до этого при регистрации через почту я использовала модуль dektrium, и таких проблем у меня с этим не было. Значит что-то не так с кодом?

Comment: все почтовые клиенты проверяют письма и на основании этих проверок пытаются вычислить является ли оно спамом или нет, в вашем случае необходимо почитать доку на mail.ru какие письма они определяют как спам, попробуйте в убрать строку "отправлено роботом" может причина в нем, а в идеале используйте готовые библиотеки для работы с почтой, такие как Mailgun

Comment: @madfan41k Спасибо буду дальше копать)

Comment: @GaLana только не закопайтесь там...